# Adding int value to string in C

Tags: c, string, int

So I've got a problem with `int` and `string` in C.

My task is to write a function that will output the error rate in `string`. 
For example if the string is `"aaabbbcccdxm"` then the output should be `"1/12"`.

By "error" I mean any letter from n to z, and any letter from a to m is "good". 
I thought that I could do it by using a `for` loop to check every letter in the string, and then `if` to add value to `int error` which would be numbers of bad letters, but I don't know how to convert that "int error" value to string with output `error value/string dimension`. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of describing your code which did not work, can you show it?

Comment: please add [mcve].

Comment: I edited your question buy you need to show us some code! Copy and paste it, select all of it and press `ctrl+k` to format it properly! That way we can help you if we can see what's wrong!

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question

Comment: @Blaze great line to UB ratio (1/1). Single line one UB

Comment: @P__J__ help me out here, what am I missing? Is it the format specifier for `strlen`?

Comment: what is the result of strlen and what format you use?

Comment: Gotcha, it is the format specifier. It should be `%zu` then, right?

Comment: As in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` to format your output. I recommend reading the `man 3 printf` on a linux machine or from google.

Here is what such a program could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

  const char *  input_str = "aaabbbcccdxm";
  int           size = strlen(input_str);
  int           error = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      if (input_str[i] >= 'n')
        error++;
    }

  printf("%d/%d\n", error, size);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: DV-ted. . Answering questions you should care about type correctness.  Using `int` as a result of strlen or sizeof is a very common beginners mistake as int has different signess & may have different size as well

Comment: @P__J__ Even tough you're right, it still answers the question about string formatting. And at this point is just being a pain, because the input string is hardcoded in the answer and therefore strlen result will implicit cast correctly without causing potential signess/information loss problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t errors(const char *str, const char *legal)
{
    size_t errcnt = 0;

    while(str && *str)
    {
        errcnt += !strchr(legal, *str++);
    }
    return errcnt;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "aaabbbcccdxm";
    printf("%zu/%zu\n", errors(str,"abcdefghijklm"), strlen(str));

    return 0;
}
```